# Как можно объединить ссылки?

Tags: html, css, css3

Привет! Имеется прайс. Необходимо, чтобы при наведении курсора на название продукта выделялась и цена данного продукта. По отдельности это не сложно сделать, а вот чтобы вместе это работало не знаю как.
Вот код:

```css
.name:hover .prise {
  background: #f3d7ff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ub-gallery">
  <div class="name"><a href="#">Unifi AP</a>
  </div>
  <div class="name"><a href="#">UniFi AP LR</a>
  </div>
  <a class="" href="images/uap.jpg">
    <img src="images/uap.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </a>
  <div class="ub-price price" id="2693">4 540 p.</div>
  <div class="ub-price price" id="20134">6 170 p.</div>
  <button class="button">Купить</button>
</div>
```

Но ничего не получилось.
 [Вот ссылка на образец](http://powerbeam.su/new/PowerBeam-M2-400.html)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте записать как-то так:

```
div.name, div.ub-price:hover {//здесь все что вам нужно}
```

Comment: не, получается, что hover только для ub-price применяется, а 1-й див чисто принимает изменения(((

Comment: @Sasha на сайте примере это сделано при поиощи JS.

Comment: спасибо! Буду искать решение в js

Comment: @Sasha там при наведении на один div меняется стиль другого. К примеру без наведения `q9` после наведения `q9 s`.

Answer (score 1):

Пример для этой разметки на css, но лучше все таки использовать javascript.

```css
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(1) ~ .price,
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(2) ~ .price + .price,
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(3) ~ .price + .price + .price,
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(4) ~ .price + .price + .price + .price,
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(5) ~ .price + .price + .price + .price + .price {
  background: #f3d7ff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(1) ~ .price ~ .price,
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(2) ~ .price + .price ~ .price,
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(3) ~ .price + .price + .price ~ .price,
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(4) ~ .price + .price + .price + .price ~ .price,
.ub-gallery .name:hover:nth-of-type(5) ~ .price + .price + .price + .price + .price ~ .price {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="ub-gallery">
  <div class="name"><a href="#">Unifi AP</a>
  </div>
  <div class="name"><a href="#">UniFi AP LR</a>
  </div>
  <div class="name"><a href="#">UniFi AP LR</a>
  </div>
  <div class="name"><a href="#">UniFi AP LR</a>
  </div>
  <div class="name"><a href="#">UniFi AP LR</a>
  </div>
  <a class="" href="images/uap.jpg">
    <img src="images/uap.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </a>
  <div class="ub-price price" id="2693">4 540 p.</div>
  <div class="ub-price price" id="20134">6 170 p.</div>
  <div class="ub-price price" id="20135">6 170 p.</div>
  <div class="ub-price price" id="20136">6 170 p.</div>
  <div class="ub-price price" id="20137">6 170 p.</div>
  <button class="button">Купить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Soledar10, спасибо за уделенное время! Буду решать с помощью js)